# Firebase Cloud Functions common functions not updated for when single function is deployed

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have multiple Firebase cloud functions which are calling some local common functions as per the following structure.

```
export const f1Delete = functions.firestore.document("col1/{doc1ID}").onDelete(async (snap, context) => {
...
reportDeleted(1);
});

export const f2Delete = functions.firestore.document("col2/{doc2ID}").onDelete(async (snap, context) => {
...
reportDeleted(2);
});

async function reportDeleted(n: number) {
...
}
```

Now, I updated the common function `reportDeleted`. When I deploy `f1Delete` and checked the files in gCloud the change is done for only function `f1Delete`. Function `f2Delete` still shows the old code.

Do I need to deploy all functions using the common method in this case to make the changes happen for all functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to deploy every function. If you deploy only `function1` then only that will be getting update helper function.

Comment: Thank you! So, after the functions are deployed each function has its own set of files.

Comment: Technically yes, every function is independent of each other.